# TypeError: this.config.plugins.filter is not a function - sfdx package install command not working

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, package, filters, sfdx-plugin, package-install

I have updated the salesforce CLi with latest version 2.21.8.

After that, i am installing the packing using `sfdx package install` commpand but i am getting below error.

```
Warning: Plugin @salesforce/plugin-packaging (1.21.1) differs from the version specified by sf (1.27.10)
TypeError: this.config.plugins.filter is not a function
```

[image]

While we check the version of CLi, we getting version information as per below.

```
$ % sf -v
@salesforce/cli/2.21.8 darwin-x64 node-v20.10.0
```

Please help to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you consider first uninstalling v1 sfdx and plugins and after that installing it from the very beginning? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_move_to_sf_v2.htm